# Erro ao integar ReactJs com PHP

Tags: php, json, react, integração, response

Olá, tudo certo? estou criando um app reactjs com php, e estou tendo dificuldades para integrar o react com um backend php.
Estou fazendo um sistema que ao clicar em um botão ele adicionará um produto ao banco de dados, porém ele retorna um erro `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` quando rodo com o react, porém rodando o mesmo código em html/js puro ele retorna o valor desejado, veja abaixo: ( usei o retorno desses valores apenas para teste )

Código php:

```
<?php

$response = ['status'=>'200', 'response'=>'ok'];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Função utilizada para conectar ao backend no React: ( caso precise do resto do código me avise que eu dou um update na pergunta, mas acredito que não seja nescessário )

```
addToShoppingCart(){
      fetch('../api/index.php')
         .then(answer => answer.json())
         .then(res => console.log(res))
      
         console.log('added')
   }
```

resultado:

```
added
VM94:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

função com html e js:

```
<body>
   <script>
      fetch('./index.php')
         .then(answer => answer.json())
         .then(res => console.log(res))
   </script>
</body>
```

resultado:

```
{status: 'ok', response: 'olá'}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer qual é o problema?
Obs: estou utilizando o XAMPP como interpretador php. Eu estav pensando que pode ser que ao utilizar o react o XAMPP não consegue ler o php, não sei se está correto, mas se for isso alguém pode me informar como resolver?

Comment: Sugiro que inspecione pelo browser o que é obtido na resposta ao pedido à API. Só assim consegue confirmar o que foi recebido, se foi mesmo o JSON direitinho ou se existe algum aviso, ou Cors ou outra coisa qualquer que "estrague" o JSON e gere esse erro.

Comment: Tem uma coisa muita estranha aqui "../api/index.php", o JS (react inclusive), roda client side, parece que você está tentando nevegar em pastas ao colocar "../api", se estiver tentando isso não vai funcionar mesmo.